# How to Retrieve value from JTextField in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

How do we retrieve value from a textfield and `actionPerformed()`? I need the value to be converted into `String` for further processing.  I have created a textfield on clicking a button I need to store the value entered into a `String` can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: Did you try reading the javadoc?

Comment: It is a duplicate. Maybe not of a single question. But this is not a new problem. [Getting text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885577/retrieve-jtextfield-text-value) & [Adding action listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062195/adding-an-action-listener-to-a-jcombobox). Plus I am sure if you would google it there is even an example for what you describe.

Comment: Its very easy to get value from  JTextfield.. try to read java doc........it will help you to develop programs..

Answer (score 70):

```
testField.getText()
```

See the java doc for [JTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Sample code can be:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      String textFieldValue = testField.getText();
      // .... do some operation on value ...
   }
})
```

Answer (score 10):

```
* First we declare JTextField like this

 JTextField  testField = new JTextField(10);

* We can get textfield value in String like this on any button click event.

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
      String getValue = testField.getText()

   }
})
```

Answer (score 8):

> How do we retrieve a value from a text field?

```
mytestField.getText();
```

`ActionListner` example:

```
mytextField.addActionListener(this);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String text = textField.getText();
    textArea.append(text + newline);
    textField.selectAll();
}
```

Comment: @trashgod : its just `"\n"` string

Comment: So maybe something like `String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");` would be correct?

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Swingtest extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JTextField txtdata;
    JButton calbtn = new JButton("Calculate");

    public Swingtest()
    {
        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
        add(myPanel);
        myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2));
        myPanel.add(calbtn);
        calbtn.addActionListener(this);
        txtdata = new JTextField();
        myPanel.add(txtdata);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource() == calbtn) {
            String data = txtdata.getText(); //perform your operation
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Swingtest g = new Swingtest();
        g.setLocation(10, 10);
        g.setSize(300, 300);
        g.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

now its working

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect. Unfortunately, this does not compile.

Comment: Please don't shout; it makes you sound angry. Even ignoring the missing imports, it looks like you're missing the constructor. Can I help you fix it?

Comment: you understand how to get value from text box so its ok

Comment: No, this is worse; I'm trying to help improve this answer. You appear to be declaring `class serverfact` and instantiating something named `VIEWBTN`. Neither name uses a style with which I am familiar.

Comment: haha ... that's cool, commanding the upvote ;-) BTW: you should stick to java naming conventions

Comment: @kleopatra is right about the naming conventions: they improve readability, e.g. `class ServerFact` or `JTextField resText`. I previously down-voted this answer because it was misleading; it is correct now, so I have reversed the vote. I'm not sure it adds anything to prior answers, but I defer to @harshini on whether it is useful. I'd be happy to examine other answers you have proposed. I can't promise an up-vote, but I can promise honest, constructive review.

Answer (score 4):

What I found helpful is this condition that is below.

```
String tempEmail = "";
JTextField tf1 = new JTextField();

tf1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt){
         tempEmail = ((JTextField)evt.getSource()).getText() + String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar());
    }
});
```

Comment: There is one problem: the control keys. they will get printed as soon as you hit them. For example, CONTROL, ALT, BACK, etc. All those keys will get printed in your string.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `event.getSource()` frim within `actionPerformed`

Cast it to the component

for Ex, if you need combobox

```
JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
JTextField txtField = (JTextField) event.getSource();
```

use appropriate api to get the value,

for Ex.

```
Object selected = comboBox.getSelectedItem();  etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getText() method anywhere in your code it is instancely called by your object, So you can use the method anywhere within a calass