# How do you access the value of a JTextField in JRuby?

Tags: jruby

I want to use the value of the text field to validate the username and password for my GUI. I have tried this code:

```
If user.Text = "abc" and passwrd.Text = "abc" then
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't seem to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You access it the [exact same as you would in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrive-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing):

```
my_text_field.getText
```

JRuby has some nice [syntactic sugar](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#alternative-names-and-beans-convention) to make interoperating with Java feel more Ruby-like, which you can also use:

```
# these are equivalent
my_text_field.get_text
my_text_field.text
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me an error that getText is not a valid method

Comment: The answer contains the code snippet - that's all there is to it. You have a reference to your field (`my_text_field`), and you call the method (`getText`, `get_text`, or `text`).

Comment: Ok ill try and get back to u if there is a problem

Comment: All the three methods are not working...i cant validate my form

Comment: "Not working" doesn't help anyone to debug your problem.