# Copy the contents of several text fields to a plain text file when clicking a JButton

Tags: java, io, jbutton, jtextfield

I have designed a GUI with JLabels, JTextFields and 4 JButtons. One of my buttons when clicked should take what the user has typed into all of the text fields and save them into a plain text file to then be able to be read by the same GUI.

I have already set up the action listeners for the buttons but cannot figure out how to write the code to copy the text from all of the text fields into a file. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: What actually you can not figure out? How to read text from text fields or how to write to the file?

Comment: It's a bit of both to be honest. I need a code to take the contents of all of my texts fields at once and copy the information into a plaintext file. Sorry if im not very specific, i'm very new to java.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how read from textField [How to Retrieve value from JTextField in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrieve-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing)

Here is how to write String to file
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/

But it's all very googlable, so next time try to search it by yourself, that is one programmer responsibilities.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks for your help. I hope i can get it to work now.