# I want to get the text from a JTextField

Tags: java, text, input, get, field

I'm trying to code a game where the user try's to guess a number, randomly generated between 1 and 10, I need to know how to get the text from the JTextField

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Guessing Game");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JButton rndbutton = new JButton("Click to create random nubmer!");
    panel.add(rndbutton);
    frame.add(panel);

    JTextField tField = new JTextField(15);
    panel.add(tField);



    //^^ The GUI code ^^



    game.game();
}
```

}

Comment: `tField.getText()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrieve-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing

Comment: When you asked the question, did it not suggest duplicates?

Comment: it is pretty straight forward - just call the `getText()` method of your JTextField. Or is ur question not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
tField.getText()
```

If you're not sure how to do something, you should first check the documentation to see if there's a function for it. Searching on Google is also a good idea.

Comment: Also, this question may have been answered before on stack overflow, so you should do a search on stack overflow first.