# How to get the Input entered on JTextField in Java using Scanner object?

Tags: java

I am learning java , I want to make one simple calculator program using GUI in Java. Idea is simple.

Calculator has 2 `JTextField` for 1st number and for 2nd number.

When I run that program will show -- `"Enter the First Number"` , below that `JTextField` to enter 1st number , below that `"Enter the Second Number"` , below that `JTextField` to enter 2nd number.

My doubt/question is How to get those input from `JTextField` and assign it to `Scanner input1` and `Scanner input2` ? Is it possible to do that ? If not what are the alternative ways ?

Hope you will understand my question , if you are in-front of me I hope I will explain it more properly .

Comment: Oh god. Format your question..!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Retrieve value from JTextField in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrieve-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `Scanner` to read data from a `JTextField`.

If the identifier of the `JTextField` is `jt`, you simply can,

```
String text = jt.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = jtext.getText().toString();
```

or if you want a number

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(jtext.getText().toString());
```

The `.toString()` is redundant but it makes the code easier to read and you will thank yourself later too!

Comment: `getText().toString()`?

Comment: Azar it makes it easier to read and since this kid is a beginner it will make it easier to read for him