# getting refrence for JTextFeild in actionListener

Tags: java, swing, reference, jtextfield, gettext

I am trying to use getText() method from a JTextFeild in an ActionListener attatched with it ... the problem is I don't have a reference that points to it ... that is I'm adding those textFeilds with in a loop that takes a string from arraylist and showing new textFeild , I searched the Internet trying to find a way to use getText() but it was pointless because I have no ref. on it , my question is how to get the text in the JTextFeild in this action Listener , and is there is any way to get a reference to this  JTextFeild that the action performed on ????

```
 JTextField t;
 for(MyClass m: MyArraylist) {
     t=new JTextField(m.toString());
     t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(getText());
                    }
                    });
      }
```

I have tried getText(); super.getText(); t.getTaxt(); and for sure it will not work because t always changes ,also i tried system.out.println(m.toString()); and does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Retrieve value from JTextField in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrieve-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the source for the event and cast it to the `TextField`

```
t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TextField tf = (TextField) e.getSource();
        System.out.println(tf.getText());
    }
});
```

Comment: I tested it. How did you test it? The action listener will only run when you press `Enter`. If you want the listener to run on every key press, you should use `KeyEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the function from the object

```
t.getText()
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752307/how-to-retrieve-value-from-jtextfield-in-java-swing/30009522)

Comment: it will not work because t always changing , also i have tried it million times before realizing that